# swift stored date turns different when formatted to string

Tags: swift, core-data, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I stored a date in core data (as a date), and with the `println` it shows correctly its value: april 21 (is the var `dateX` below), but when right after the `println` I format it to string with the following code, the label linked to it shows april 22 (which is today, so I wonder tomorrow will show 23 etc.), where is the problem?

```
if dateX != nil{
            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
            dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
            var dateXstring = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateX as NSDate)
           startLabel.text = "Profile created on \(dateXstring)"
        }
```

println dateX and dateXstring:

[image]

my time zone is Rome (Italy)

Comment: yea i saw the other threads so i've added the timeZone to the formatter but it doesn't seem to help idk why, i've edited with println and time zone, thanks

Comment: It is the same problem as so often :) – NSDate does not have a timezone, and its description always uses UTC. `2015-04-21 22:53:34 +0000` is the same as `2015-04-22 00:53:34` in your local timezone (GMT+2).

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a timezone issue.  Where are you located?  `DefaultTimeZone` could be GMT/ZULU time which is -5 hrs from the east coast.

A good way to check is to use the `timeIntervalSince1970` function (i think thats what it is called).  If the stored date and retrieved date have the same value its the same date and you have a display problem.

`timeIntervalSince1970` returns a `NSTimeInterval` which is really a `Double`